# Split an array into multiple subarrays to minimize the sum of each individual subarray

Tags: algorithm, optimization, dynamic-programming

**The Problem Statement**

Given an array A of some length N, divide it into K subarrays (not necessarily contiguous) such that sum of elements in each of the individual subarrays is as close as possible to sum(A)/K.

**Mathematical Version**

The above is the statement of the problem that I came across but it does not give us the exact function that we need to optimize. To me, the following optimization problem seems to have the same meaning (correct me if I am wrong):

[image]
where,  [image]
, [image] is the [image] subarray and [image] is just the sum of all the elements of an array [image].

I stumbled across this problem and have no idea how to approach it. If it is really simple, just give me the right direction, and please don't provide a complete answer. I searched before posting and all of the related problems that I found talked about contiguous subarrays which is not what I am looking for.

Thanks in advance.

**Edits**

1. Every element of A goes into exactly one of the subarrays (No repetitions).
2. The number of elements in each subarray need not be the same.
3. K is given as a part of the problem itself and need not be found.

Comment: Have you tried the naive approach of splitting it into directly subarray based on index and shuffling elements between subarray with the largest errors in opposite directions?

Comment: @Mansoor I tried the greedy approach of maintaining a difference array which stores how far are all the sums of subarrays from the maximum subarray sum. And then using that to take the greedy step (i.e. choosing an array which gives maximum difference and putting the element closest to the maximum difference in that array). This approach seems to work well but I am pretty sure this doesn't provide the optimal solution.

Comment: @Mansoor Could you please elaborate on your suggested approach? I don't understand how you are splitting based on the index and your shuffling criteria. Are you suggesting to sort the array in descending order and then have an initial state for subarrays where ith subarray gets elements whose indexes are i modulo K in initial array? I tried this one and it seems to work worse than the one I mentioned above.

Comment: Do the number of elements in each sub-array need to be the same? (could you redo the maths in markdown and not as images).

Comment: @Mansoor Apart from the ones mentioned in the question, there are no other restrictions. So, No. The number of elements in each sub-array need not be same. And about the math, well I searched and found a post on meta that said math rendering isn't available on SO. I preferred to use images because in plain text (or markdown), the math would look really ugly. Could you suggest me a better way?

Comment: Ok, so a simplified approach would be to split the problem into two half. An initial phase where you make an initial guess at the subarrays. You already have the loss function, you can then suggest moving items from those with +ve errors to those with -ve errors and check that the loss function reduces with each step. Obviously, this is a very simple approach that is neither computationally efficient nor will it converge to an optimal solution because it will not change the number of subarrays once it starts.

Comment: This is sort of a neural network type of approach, minimizing the loss at every iteration. But as you rightly pointed out, it does not know how to increase the number of sub-arrays if K > 2. Maybe we can create K splits initially itself and then do as you say. However, I am not sure if we have an optimal way of deciding the shuffling part for K > 2.